# Replace Text using powershell

Tags: security, powershell, automation

I am having a text file with the following content:

```
some text
some text some text some text
somevariable=334,321;  
somevariable=234,234;
some text b = 34 some text some text
```

I want to replace the line

```
somevariable=334,321;
```

with

```
somevariable=10,20;
```

I can do this using following way

```
 $content.replace("somevariable=334,321;", "somevariable=10,20;")
```

But the problem is I somevariable can be anything and I want to replace it with my values.

```
$content.replace("somevariable=?,?", "somevariable=10,20;")
```

can you tell me how can I update my variable in a text file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-replace` operator, it takes a regex pattern as it's first rhs argument:

```
$content -replace '(?<=somevariable=)\d+,\d+;','10,20;'
```

Comment: Hi, when I am executing this getting error "The regular expression pattern is not valid"

Comment: @yogeshkmrsoni what is the real value of `somevariable`? does it contain any special characters? They will need escaping

Comment: have a look on this : PS C:\Windows\system32> (gc E:\secpol.cfg) -replace '(?<=MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\LmCompatibilityLevel=)\d+,\d+','4,5' | Out-File E:\secpol.cfg

Comment: Yes, \ will need escaping: \\. Alternatively, search only for the last part of the string in the lookahead: `(?<=LMCompatibilityLevel=)\d+,\d+;`

Comment: Thanks @ Mathias R. Jessen it worked, can you tell me from where can i learn regular exp basics..

Comment: @yogeshkmrsoni Just google "regular expression", plenty of material out there :-) Be aware that since PowerShell is running on .NET, it's using the same regex engine/flavor as C#

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `regex` with the `-replace` method:

```
$content -replace "somevariable=.*$", "somevariable=10,20;"
```